# How do I use operators in LuaBridge

Tags: c++, binding, lua, bind, luabridge

I'm trying to export my vectors class

```
            .beginClass<Vector>("Vector")
            .addConstructor<void(*)()>()
            .addConstructor<void(*)(float, float, float)>()
            .addFunction("__eq", &Vector::operator==)
            .addFunction("__add", &Vector::operator+)
            .addData("x", &Vector::x)
            .addData("y", &Vector::y)
            .addData("z", &Vector::z)
            .addFunction("Length", &Vector::Length)
            .addFunction("Angle", &Vector::Angle)
            .addFunction("Distance", &Vector::DistTo)
        .endClass()
```

but when i try and do the other 3 operators, I have multiple overloads for them. How can I specify which one I want to use and is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I just made an add/subtract/multiply/divide function and called that instead. Guess operators just don't want to comply.

Comment: I encountered exactly the same problem, but I managed to solve it:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49490076/luabridge-binding-overloaded-operators/49498449#49498449. Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

If you have a function overloads `int MyClass::Func(int)` and `MyClass* MyClass::Func(MyClass)` then you can define the overload to use in the following manner. In this example I chose to use `MyClass* MyClass::Func(MyClass)` as overload.

```
.addFunction("Func", (MyClass*(MyClass::*)(MyClass)) &MyClass::Func)
```

So what happens here is that the function signature is provided with the pointer to the function.

Comment: I tried to do that with my operator- but without success
`.addFunction("__sub", (Vector(Vector::*)(const Vector&)) &Vector::operator-)`

`Vector Vector::operator-(const Vector& v) const {
  return Vector(x - v.x, y - v.y, z - v.z);
 }`

Comment: @Snorflake Try adding the const too like this: `.addFunction("__sub", (Vector (Vector::* const)(const Vector&)) &Vector::operator-)`

Comment: still nothing. It's okay, I posted my solution below anyways.

Answer (score 0):

infect luabridge can implement this in this way,
if you define a class A

```
.addFunction("__eq", &A::equal )
```

'equal' should be declared like:

```
bool A::equal( const A & )
```

then :

```
if obj1 == obj2 then
end
```

'equal' will work!

but if you implement a sub class of A
class B : public A

it's will takes you a lot of time!

first you have to Specialization the template class or the template method

```
luabridge::UserdataValue 

luabridge::UserdataPtr::push(lua_State* const L, T* const p)
```

the specify which class's (meta)table you need to regist the object or the pointer

you should read luabridge's sourcecode to accomplish this!

Then!

you should regist this function to B again!

```
.addFunction("__eq", &B::equal )
```

lua code :

```
local inst_a = app.new_class_A();
local inst_b = app.new_class_B();
-- this will call the '__eq' in B's metatable
if( inst_b == inst_a )then
end
-- this will call the '__eq' in A's metatable
if( inst_a == inst_b )then
end
```

while calling __eq, luabridge will not search the class's parent's metadata table, so you should regist again to A's subclass!

hope it will help you!
sorry for my poor english!